# How to get a string with new address using coinbase api and php

Tags: php, api, bitcoin, coinbase-api

i'm trying to use Coinbase Wallet PHP Library (from here:https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php) .

`$client->createAccountAddress($account, $address);` - when i using it - creates new address. But i want to print in to the customer.

`$address = $client->getAccountAddress($account, $addressId);` - I tried to use it, but i dont know what to put in $addressId variable. Could you please help me.

Example of the code that i'm using:

```
    <?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Address;

parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);

$apiKey = 'myApi';
$apiSecret = 'apiSecret';


$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);

$account = $client->getPrimaryAccount();

$address = new Address([
    'name' => 'New Address16'
]);

$client->createAccountAddress($account, $address);
$addresses = $client->getAccountAddress($account, $address); //i don't know what to put in second variable
echo "network: ".json_encode($addresses->getAddress)."<br>";

?>
```

Comment: I cant understend, what should i put in $addressId variable. Maybe someone could explain it to me?
`$address = $client->getAccountAddress($account, $addressId);`

Answer (score 4):

So, thats how it works, it is generate a new address and print it.

```
    <?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Address;

parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);

$apiKey = 'api';
$apiSecret = 'secret';


$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);

$account = $client->getPrimaryAccount();

$address = new Address([
    'name' => 'New Address19'
]);

$add = $client->createAccountAddress($account, $address);
$addressId = $client->getAccountAddresses($account);
$addresses = $client->getAccountAddress($account, $addressId->getFirstId());
echo "Your address is: ".json_encode($addresses->getAddress())."<br>";
?>
```